# RESTful: bidirectional communication

Tags: rest, client-server

I was wondering if it is possible to have a RESTful web service and a bidirectional communication with the clients and server.

In my case the state on the server can change, so the server should send a message to the clients to update themself. Perhaps that's totally against the RESTful idea.

Can I AJAX help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: From what i understand of REST, yes, state is against REST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really possible under the standard http paradigm, but check out [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for a possible workaround on that problem and there is alway polling.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are after is treated by the concept of [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets), but they are not mainstream yet.

To keep your solution RESTful you can have the clients poll your service.  You can optimize any number of ways, like implementing a special method that lets clients query for changes given a timestamp, then the client just keeps track of when it last checked.

Comment: is there a browser supporting web sockets already? I saw that JBoss Netty supports this connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/). BOSH is similar to Comet, but more specific, and I think, there are more reliable implementations.

Though, you will have problems serving multiple users at the same time if you want to use a standard REST service. You should think of some other implementation using nonblocking IO.
There are probably more questions about [bosh](/questions/tagged/bosh). Of course, there are [websockets](/questions/tagged/websockets) now too, but if you need to serve old Browsers, you cannot rely on them.